How do we Serialize a File Attachment which has an RFC message
I have a unique scenario where in an .eml file is sent as file Attachment .I am not sure how to deserialize it using microsoft-graph-api..using latest version 6.16.0
I have also added how a sample response looks like , as you see in th below code processing an itemAttachment is quite straight forward
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('foo%40bar.com')/messages('AAMkAGI4NjFmZjQwLTMyOWEtNDI5MS05M2JmLTZhZGY0YzM5MmM5NQBGAAAAAAAxxAUGikUbRotDsfglXTlaBwCZx2ecKdkYRqinPi0NZhdPAAAAAAEMAACZx2ecKdkYRqinPi0NZhdPAAE5suHaAAA%3D')/attachments",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "message/rfc822",
            "id": "AAMkAGI4NjFmZjQwLTMyOWEtNDI5MS05M2JmLTZhZGY0YzM5MmM5NQBGAAAAAAAxxAUGikUbRotDsfglXTlaBwCZx2ecKdkYRqinPi0NZhdPAAAAAAEMAACZx2ecKdkYRqinPi0NZhdPAAE5suHaAAABEgAQAO1R5rkS-AJDnpgFzy8Z_XI=",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-10-01T20:53:49Z",
            "name": "message.eml",
            "contentType": "message/rfc822",
            "size": 3684,
            "isInline": false,
            "contentId": null,
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "someRandomByte--Omitted for brevity "
        }
    ]
}

 private List<Message> convertAttachmentsToMessageList(List<Attachment> attachmentListPage) {

        List<Message> attachmentMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        attachmentListPage.stream().forEach(attachment -> {
            if (attachment instanceof FileAttachment) {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachment;
                if (fileAttachment.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("message/rfc822")) {
                    //TODO how do we seralize this
                }
            } else if (attachment instanceof ItemAttachment) {
                ItemAttachment itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment) attachment;
                OutlookItem item = itemAttachment.getItem();
                if (item instanceof Message) {
                    attachmentMessages.add((Message) item);
                }

            }
        });

        return attachmentMessages;
    }


If you have a message/rfc822 attachment what will be in the contentBytes is the MIME encoded message. The Graph API or SDK won't decode the Message or deserialize back to a Graph Mail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0  resource type. You have to deal with the Mime Message locally and decode and read the properties (you want or care about) using another library eg in Java something like https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html should work.
